# Authenticate using Box Android SDK v2

Tags: android, box-api

I want to authenticate using the Box SDK.

I got the [Box Java SDK V2](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2) and the [Box Android SDK V2](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk-v2).
And I'm using the [basic authentication code](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk-v2#basic-authentication) from the Box Android SDK

```
Intent intent = OAuthActivity.createOAuthActivityIntent(this, clientId, 
    clientSecret);
startActivityForResult(intent);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Get the error message for why authentication failed.
        String failMessage = data.getStringExtra(OAuthActivity.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        // Implement your own logic to handle the error.
       handleFail(failMessage);
    } else {
        // You will get an authenticated BoxClient object back upon success.
        BoxClient client =
            data.getParcelableExtra(OAuthActivity.BOX_CLIENT);
        youOwnMethod(client);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
The method createOAuthActivityIntent(Context, String, String) from the type OAuthActivity refers to the missing type Intent
```

It's probably something stupid I'm doing wrong, but can someone tell me what?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Intent class cannot be found? This is an android class. Are you working on an android project or a regular java project? Do you see any compile error?